# Python: Passing a class member function to another class's callback

Tags: python, callback, raspberry-pi, robotics

Can I pass class A into class B so that B can run a callback using A's member function?

I am trying to write a Python leg class for a robot I am building. I am using  a Raspberry Pi as the main computer, and Martin O'Hanlon's KY040 rotary encoder library [KY040](https://github.com/martinohanlon/KY040) to detect each 1/4 rotation of the leg. To this end, I watch for the first of several clicks, sleep for a short time, stop the servo, and now a 1/4 rotation has been achieved. In standalone, unthreaded code this works fine, but creating a class has been a challenge.

**Details:**

A threaded sentinel loop watches a boolean (`quarterTurn`) to signal that a rotation must be carried out.

```
def run(self):
    print "leg running"
    while self._running:
        sleep(.0001)
        if self.quarterTurn:
            print "quarterTurn is: " + str(self.quarterTurn)
            self.qTurn(self.quarterCount)
```

`qTurn` accesses a pwm controller to activate the motors, and reset quarterTurn to false.

```
def qTurn(self, quarters):
    count = 0

    while count < quarters:
        sleep(.0001)
        self.setMotor(self.maxPulse)

        if self.ClickedOnce:
            count = count + 1
            sleep(.17)
            self.parkMotor()
            sleep(.04)
            self.clickedOnce = False

    self.quarterTurn = False
```

The trick is that O'Hanlon's class is already threaded. On one hand, it is convenient, on the other, it makes my class more complex. The KY040 makes use of a callback function to provide feedback, but using this within my class is the source of my trouble.

I need the callback to modify a a boolean in my leg class, but this function is only called by the KY040 class, which tries to pass itself into the function.

```
def rotaryChange(self, pin):
    self.clickedOnce = True
```

Since the code is open source (thank you, O'Hanlon), I thought I could modify the constructor of the KY040 to let me pass my leg class into it, so that I could modify the correct data.

O'Hanlon's Original Constructor:

```
def __init__(self, clockPin, dataPin, switchPin=None, rotaryCallback=None, switchCallback=None,rotaryBouncetime=250, switchBouncetime=300):
    # persist values
    self.clockPin = clockPin
    self.dataPin = dataPin
    self.switchPin = switchPin
    self.rotaryCallback = rotaryCallback
    self.switchCallback = switchCallback
    self.rotaryBouncetime = rotaryBouncetime
    self.switchBouncetime = switchBouncetime

    #setup pins
    GPIO.setup(clockPin, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(dataPin, GPIO.IN)

    if None != self.switchPin:
        GPIO.setup(switchPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
```

I added a "host" variable, into which I pass the leg class:

```
def __init__(self, clockPin, dataPin, switchPin=None, rotaryCallback=None, switchCallback=None, host=None, rotaryBouncetime=250, switchBouncetime=300):
    # persist values
    self.clockPin = clockPin
    self.dataPin = dataPin
    self.switchPin = switchPin
    self.rotaryCallback = rotaryCallback
    self.switchCallback = switchCallback
    self.rotaryBouncetime = rotaryBouncetime
    self.switchBouncetime = switchBouncetime

    # My Change
    self.host = host

    #setup pins
    GPIO.setup(clockPin, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(dataPin, GPIO.IN)

    if None != self.switchPin:
        GPIO.setup(switchPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
```

The modified constructor would be called like so:

```
self.encoder = KY040(self.clockPin, self.dataPin, rotaryCallback=self.rotaryChange, host=self)
```

O'Hanlon's callback now passes the host along:

```
def _clockCallback(self, pin):
        # My change
        self.rotaryCallback(pin, self.host)
```

My new callback:

```
def rotaryChange(pin, host):
    host.clickedOnce = True
```

Unfortunately, after making sure the modified code is installed with the setup script, it doesn't seem to acknowledge my new additions. I run my program and receive the follwing error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "ctf.py", line 18, in <module>
      LR = leg.leg(lr_chan, lr_max, lr_park, lr_clk, lr_data);
    File "/home/[user]/hexacrescentapod/leg.py", line 47, in __init__
      self.encoder = KY040(self.clockPin, self.dataPin, 
    rotaryCallback=self.rotaryChange, host=self)
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'host'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little confusing because of your wording. Are you actually trying to pass a *class* in as you say, or an *instance* of that class as you seem to be doing? Which class is `rotaryChange` defined in?

Anyway, it looks like what you're actually trying to do is pass `self.rotaryChange` as a callback.

This already works, without any changes. `self.rotaryChange` is a bound method, meaning it knows what that `self` was when it was created, and will pass it when it's called. This may be easier to see with an example:

```
>>> class Spam:
...     def eggs(self):
...         pass
>>> spam = Spam()
>>> spam
<__main__.Spam at 0x119947630>
>>> spam.eggs
<bound method Spam.eggs of <__main__.Spam object at 0x119947630>>
```

Notice that it's a bound method *of the `spam` object*. When you call `spam.eggs()`, that `spam` object will be passed as the `self` argument.

This means you don't need to pass a `host` in, because it's already available as `self`. And, since that's the only thing you do with `host`, you don't need to pass around `host` in the first place. Which means you can revert all of your changes to the library code.

You *do* need to define your callback method as a proper method, with `self` as the first argument. But that's it. Then you can just pass `rotaryCallback=self.rotaryChange` to the constructor, and everything will work.

Comment: That's very interesting. I'll give it a try, and let you know what happens.

Comment: @GageGeigle Most Python tutorials don’t cover bound methods, maybe because they look kind of scary, but they’re very useful—so useful that tutorials often end up using them even though they never explained them. One thing that may help is to consider that you can write a function that just does `return spam.eggs()` and pass that around, store it in a variable and call it later, whatever, and then you can do the same thing by just passing around `spam.eggs` itself, and see that there is never a difference (except for names and speed).

Answer (score 1):

At a first look, it looks like your new callback is missing a `self` field?

The original function was

```
def rotaryChange(self, pin):
    self.clickedOnce = True
```

But your implementation is:

```
def rotaryChange(pin, host):
    host.clickedOnce = True
```

If this function sits inside a class it needs to have a `self` parameter

Comment: Indeed, I too thought passing `self` was a requirement for a class member, but changing to the second implementation was the only way I could think of to keep the KY040 class from passing itself into the `self` parameter.

Comment: @GageGeigle This is part of the reason Python uses explicit `self`, so it’s always clear whose `self` is being passed. If the code inside `KY040` is not calling `self.something` where `something` is a method name from the class or a subclass, it isn’t passing itself. However, callables stored in instance variables can get confusing at times. You have to notice that `self.callback` is assigned inside `__init__` or some other method body to know that it’s not a method and therefore not passing its own `self`.

Comment: @GageGeigle When you’re not sure, it’s often worth building a toy class with the same pattern, but none of the rest of the code, so you can just run it and print out what gets called.

Comment: @abarnert Thank you very much. I'll do that.